# Difference between using a single repository and a single mirror

Tags: maven

The maven documentation says:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

> Using A Single Repository. You can force Maven to use a single
>   repository by having it mirror all repository requests. The repository
>   must contain all of the desired artifacts, or be able to proxy the
>   requests to other repositories. This setting is most useful when using
>   an internal company repository with the Maven Repository Manager to
>   proxy external requests.
>
> To achieve this, set mirrorOf to *.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
      <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

I don't understand this paragraph.

Shouldn't it be something like this?

> Using A Single **Mirror** You can force Maven to use a single
>   **mirror** by having it mirror all repository requests. The **mirror** must contain all of the desired artifacts **for all the
>   repositories**, or be able to proxy the requests to other
>   repositories. This setting is most useful when using an internal
>   company repository with the Maven Repository Manager to proxy external
>   requests. To achieve this, set mirrorOf to *.

```
 <settings>
   ...
   <mirrors>
     <mirror>
       <id>internal-mirror</id>
       <name>Maven Mirror Manager running on mirror.mycompany.com</name>
       <url>http://mirror.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
       <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
     </mirror>
   </mirrors>
   ...
 </settings>
```

Where is my miss-understanding?

I mean, `<mirror><id>internal-repository</id>...` seems just wrong to me.

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073865/3281336 might be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mirror means a repository that is used as a passerelle/proxy to an other repository. 
When using a repository manager like Nexus, Artiafactory, Archiva... you dispose of one local entreprise repository wich proxifies remotes ones.
So there is no need to declare too many repositories in your pom or setting.xml. Using Just one mirror which redirect all requests to the repository manager you have will be sufficient.
That is the meaning of the documentation.

Comment: but if I work with repo-manager (Artifactory), can't I declare a single repo in my settings.xml, which is my repo-manager, instead of using mirror?

Comment: @napilioni I might be late but would like to understand. Instead of declaring a mirror, I can straight away declare that in the repository itself right?  I don't get the purpose of mirror.

Answer (score 0):

As maven documentation says:

> Repositories can be declared inside a project, which means that if you have your own custom repositories, those sharing your project easily get the right settings out of the box. However, you may want to use an alternative mirror for a particular repository **without changing the project files**.

For repositories in **settings.xml**, declaring mirrors for them is redundant because you can just replace the repositories directly.

For repositories listed in the **pom.xml**, you may want to keep it untouched if it is a group or public project. If you change the repos in the pom.xml, others may fail to connect to those repos. The correct solution here is to add mirrors for those repos in your own setting.xml.

For example. Project X is a public project that list all the repos it required in its pom.xml.

- Most people can just download the dependencies and build the project directly.
- Alex wants to build the project on his company PC, and his company has an internal enterprice repo. So he uses the company repo in his settings.xml as a mirror to speed up the downloading.
- Bob cannot access some project repos directly due to connection issue. He can use other public mirrors for that repo.