# Understand the use of mirror and repositories

Tags: maven

I have a Nexus OSS server configured as my Repository. I'm trying to configure the settings.xml to this server and central:

```
   <settings>
  <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>   
  </mirrors>


</settings>
```

In my Nexus Repo (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) i just have the following files (i uploaded the mylib.jar in thirdparty repo):

```
archetype-catalog.xml   Fri May 27 12:17:45 BRT 2016    25
```

But when i tried to mvn:install the maven don't find my JAR in Thrid Part repository, i got the error:

```
The POM for br.com:mylib:jar:2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757902/what-is-mirror-in-maven-settings-xml-file it explains the mirror configuration (and will show that you have a weird config here, mainly mirroring `central` to point at it again).

Comment: Cool, i read everything but i have a doubt. The maven give preferences to <repository> instead of <mirror> ? So, i can have <repository> without <mirror> but i can't have <mirror> without <repository> right ?

Comment: Yes, you can mirror `central` which is Maven Central and present by default without configuring it with a repository.

Comment: As i said i have a Nexus server (showed in settings.xml as <mirrorOf>*) , i need a repository ? I'm asking this because i can't find my jar, the maven throws a exception

Comment: Since your configuration redirects all requests (as seen by `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`) to your Nexus repo, you actually don't need the reposirories declaration.

Comment: Do you have any ideia why maven can't find my jar in nexus repo ? I already uploaded and added in pom.xml the dependency

Comment: Well, I'd try to remove your `<repositories>` declaration since you don't need them, then your `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>` also, you don't need it and it's confusing. Then you need to make sure that `http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/br/com/mylib/2.0/mylib-2.0.jar` exists.

Comment: I found the problem, i didn't put the repository in GROUP.,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113165/discussion-between-scientist-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 0):

Your mirror settings will work. I almost said they were "fine" but that's an overstatement.  They should work for the situation you have presented.

IF: 
You succesfully loaded `br.com:mylib:2.0` into the `thirdparty` repo (are you sure?  It should probably be `com.br`, but what do I know...)
AND: 
You can find it in the `thirdparty` repo within the nexus browser
THEN:
You should be able to resolve it without specifying any additional repositories.

Sounds like your config of Nexus doesn't have your third-party library in the `groups/public` group, which is what you're using as your mirror source for `central`.

Make sure that `public` includes `thirdparty`

I use Nexus 3 which, by default, doesn't include any such repository.