# Project repository is ignored if mirrors are configured in the settings.xml

Tags: maven, repository, maven-3

I've created a project repository using this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

This works fine if I comment out the `mirrors` definition in the `settings.xml` file in the .m2 folder. 
If the mirrors are defined, the project repository is not considered. Do I have to add it as a mirror as well? It would be great if this can be somehow handled inside the `pom.xml`.

pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
<mirror>
  <id>de.companyname.repository.release</id>
  <mirrorOf>de.companyname.repository</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://repository.companyname.de/content/repositories/releases</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>de.companyname.repository</id>
  <mirrorOf>de.companyname.repository</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://repository.companyname.de/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>nexus-else</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
  <mirrorOf>central-snapshots</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal, and is actually the wanted use-case of [mirrors](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html). They are used in order to have Maven download dependencies from another location that the one defined in `<repository>` element. More info on how it does that [in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36763588/1743880).

In your case, you have this mirror configuration:

```
<mirror>
  <id>nexus-else</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

which means that this `<mirror>` will mirror `*`, i.e. all repositories. So your `repo` declaration inside your POM is not being taken into account, because this mirror is configured to mirror it. As such, every request that Maven would have made at `file://${project.basedir}/repo` is in fact redirected to your mirror URL. You have two solutions here:

- Don't tell `nexus-else` to mirror local file based repository. You can do that with

  ```
  <mirror>
    <id>nexus-else</id>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>
  ```

  > `external:*` matches all repositories except those using localhost or file based repositories. This is used in conjunction with a repository manager when you want to exclude redirecting repositories that are defined for Integration Testing.

  Since your `repo` declaration is a file repository poiting to your localhost, it won't be mirrored by `nexus-else`. This also makes sure that any other file based repository on your localhost that you add in the future won't be mirrored as well.
- Exclude `repo` from the mirror configuration with:

  ```
  <mirror>
    <id>nexus-else</id>
    <mirrorOf>*,!repo</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://nexus.companyname.de:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>
  ```

  > `*,!repo1` = everything except repo1

  This solution might be more fragile than the one above, because you need to hard-code the id of the repository.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This was very helpful as it explains the exact same problem I am facing on my project.  At least I now know it's not possible and settings.xml will have to be changed.