# Why mirror is needed in maven while we can just modify the repository?

Tags: maven

I have read [difference in maven using a single repository or a single mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063213/difference-in-maven-using-a-single-repository-or-a-single-mirror). But still have confusion.

As we can just modify the repository setting, why adding another mirror setting to make it proxy other repositories?

I tested it works completely normal when setting nexus as a repository. So I just want to know what's the benefit if mirror?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to define additional repositories in pom files. If you define a mirror, those are overridden, otherwise not.

So if you definitely want to avoid that MavenCentral in contacted, use a mirror.